# django tastypie populate fields using current user resource

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose i have :

models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

api.py

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    #blhblahblah as usual

class BooksResource(ModelResource):

    owner= fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'owner')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Books.objects.all()
        authorizarion = Authorization()
```

Then i issue :

`curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{\"owner\" : \"/api/v1/user/1/\", \"title\" : \"foo\"}" http://localhost:8000/api/data/album/`

And it's working, i got my new `Books`

Then i try to get rid the `\"owner\" : \"/api/v1/user/1/\"`  by adding this to the `BooksResource`

```
def hydrate_owner(self, bundle):
    bundle.obj.owner = User.objects.get(pk = bundle.request.user.id)
    return bundle
```

When i do `curl` again without the `\"owner\" : \"/api/v1/user/1/\"`, the response is `404 not found`

Then i try different method :

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request = None, **kwargs):
    return super(BooksResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, owner = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.id))
```

or

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request = None, **kwargs):
    return super(BooksResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, owner = User.objects.get(pk = bundle.request.user.id))
```

I still get `404 not found`

can guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

Doh, apparently it was my stupid mistake,

```
class BooksResource(ModelResource):

    owner= fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'owner')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Books.objects.all()
        authorizarion = Authorization()

        def hydrate_owner(self, bundle):
            bundle.obj.owner = bundle.request.user.id
            return bundle
```

The mistake is the indentation! `hydrate_owner` suppose to be `BooksResource` method, so i changed the code a bit and it works:

```
class BooksResource(ModelResource):

    owner= fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'owner')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Books.objects.all()
        authorizarion = Authorization()

    def hydrate_owner(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['owner'] = User.objects.get(pk = bundle.request.user.pk)
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

I started down this path for path to set owners for new objects, but I got into trouble when doing authorization checking on an update request (go unit testing!).

Setup:
Object A - owned by user X
Update request from user Y to modify object A (which should fail)

The modification request to an object A comes in to Tasty Pie from user Y and the hydrate override would set the owner to Y in the working copy of object A.

Next the request is sent to my Authorization object to check if user Y can modify the object.  My authorization code looks in the object and sees that the object's owner field is Y so we're good to go.  Yikes! Security hole!

What I decided to do was to override obj_create() in the ResourceModel and do the assignment there.  So far, so good!

For example

```js
class SmApiNewsItem(ModelResource):
    owner = fields.ForeignKey(SmApiUser, 'owner')
    
    class Meta:
        if SMARF_AUTH_ON:
            authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ScsGdnAuthVisibleToAllEditOnlyByOwner()
        queryset = SmModelNewsItems.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'news_item'
        filtering = smMakeFilterAllFieldsFilter(SmModelNewsItems)
        ordering = smMakeOrderingFieldList(SmModelNewsItems)
        serializer = SmarfSerializer()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.data["owner"] = bundle.request.user
        return super(SmApiNewsItem, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
```